# Продление времени жизни временного объекта путем связывания с ним ссылки на константное значение

Tags: c++, const, ссылка

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
Object GetObject()
{
    // ...
    return Object{someValue};
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const Object& object = GetObject();
    object.GetName();
    return 0;
}
```

Насколько мне известно, `Стандарт` позволяет нам создавать ссылку на константный объект и связывать эту ссылку со временным значением. Такая ссылка будет держать временный объект (продлевать срок его жизни) до тех пор, пока существует сама ссылка.

А теперь рассмотрим еще один вариант кода:

```
const Object& GetObject()
{
    // ...
    return Object{someValue};
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const Object& object = GetObject();
    object.GetName();
    return 0;
}
```

Я не знаю, можно ли так делать или нельзя, но я склоняюсь к тому, что так делать нельзя.

С одной стороны, здесь тоже ссылка на константный объект, но насколько мне известно, возвращение ссылки на локальный объект функции/метода - это *большая ошибка*.

Мне интуитивно понятно, почему `Стандарт` позволяет продлевать время жизни временного объекта в первом случае. Такое поведение достаточно безопасно и весьма удобно.

Но я не совсем понимаю, как `Стандарт` регламентирует второй вариант кода. И почему он его регламентирует именно так.

Comment: А где вы увидели ссылки на локальные объекты? Вы же возвращаете копию, а она в свою очередь, будет скопирована, и лежать в сетке вызывающей функции.

Comment: Не нужно так делать. Во-первых из-за RVO, а, во-вторых, потому что объект будет уничтожен после выхода из функции `getObject`.

Comment: Что тут может быть непонятно? Объект локален для функции, передаётся по ссылке, функция завершается, стек очищается. Как это можно ещё регламентировать?

Comment: Ну всё правильно. Создали + уничтожили объект, ссылка инвалидирована на него, как и указатель. А в первом варианте создания в функции вообще нет, создание уже в мейне (кстати, у вас нестандартный тип у функции `main`) + продление жизни, уничтожения объекта нет - пользуемся

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, поправил тип функции `main()`.